# Making Google Scripts Available to Multiple Files from a Custom Menu in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a number of scripts that I want to be available to files that I will create in the future.  I'd like to be able to access those scripts from a custom menu at the top of my Google Sheets file.  I've spent a lot of time looking around, and can't find clear information on this.

Its not stated clearly, but seems that unbound scripts can only be run from scripts.google.com.  Is this the case?

Any ideas how to make this available in a custom drop down menu from future files I will create?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use script in all spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221994/use-script-in-all-spreadsheets)

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14791331/1595451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know that is only possible with addons.

https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/editors/sheets